# How can I make 3d plot with stacked 2d plot?

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I want to plot as below. I tried to search several packages and plot functions but I couldn't find a solution.

My data has four columns.

```
ID  F  R  M
 1  2  3  4
 2  4  6  7
...
```

I want to see the relationship between `M` and `R` with respect to each `F` value (1, 2, 3, ...). So, I'd like `F` along the x-axis, `R` along the y-axis, and `M` as the z-axis as in the below graph.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried apart from searching? what is your use case or sample dataset? Provide some more information...

Comment: I edited and explained more. Thanks!

Comment: That seems a bit weak on the volume of data for a sample dataset. It's not going to make a very interesting graph. I've see somewhat similar images in the _Lattice_ text and I would not think it would be particularly difficult in pkg-`rgl`

Comment: I'd skip the 3D, and use color for the third dimension. Already in the example you show, part of the graphs in the back are obscured by graphs before it.

Comment: Have a look at the problem with occlusion that Stephen Few (respected graphing expert) says about 3-D graphics on page 17: http://mkt.tableausoftware.com/downloads/TCC08-Keynote-Stephen-Few.pdf @jbaums gives a correct answer to the wrong question (+1 to him).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this kind of thing with `lattice` `cloud` plots, using `panel.3dpolygon` from `latticeExtra`.

```
library(latticeExtra)

# generating random data
d <- data.frame(x=rep(1:40, 7), y=rep(1:7, each=40), 
                z=c(sapply(1:7, function(x) runif(40, 10*x, 10*x+20))))

# define the panel function
f <- function(x, y, z, groups, subscripts, ...) {
  colorz <- c('#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', 
              '#fdb462', '#b3de69')
  sapply(sort(unique(groups), decreasing=TRUE), function(i) {
    zz <- z[subscripts][groups==i]
    yy <- y[subscripts][groups==i]
    xx <- x[subscripts][groups==i]    
    panel.3dpolygon(c(xx, rev(xx)), c(yy, yy), 
                    c(zz, rep(-0.5, length(zz))), 
                    col=colorz[i], ...)
  })

}

# plot
cloud(z~x+y, d, groups=y, panel.3d.cloud=f, scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

I'm sure I don't need to loop over `groups` in the panel function, but I always forget the correct incantation for `subscripts` and `groups` to work as intended.

As others have mentioned in comments, this type of plot might look snazzy, but can obscure data.

[image]