# 3D plot with stacked 2D plots and show relationship between their means

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to recreate a figure similar to the attached plot (similar to the target plot). 
[image]

I have found certain topics that are similar (e.g. one 3D plot comprising stacked 2D plots ([How can I make 3d plot with stacked 2d plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236953/how-can-i-make-3d-plot-with-stacked-2d-plot)) or plotting mean for density distributions ([plot median values on top of a density distribution in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960277/plot-median-values-on-top-of-a-density-distribution-in-ggplot2))).

But I was unable to find an example in which there is a 3D plot of stacked 2D plots and, in addition, there is a plot of showing the relationship between the mean values of the said stacked 2D plots.

Thanks

Comment: ggplot2 doesn't do 3d plotting. I have read that there are no plans to change than. Bothe base plotting and lattice plotting can do it. For a coding answer you need to provid data.

Comment: it's called a ridgeplot I guess, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html see that package: ggridges

Comment: I think it's *possible* to hack this in ggplot2 / ggridges, & shift the individual density lines to simulate 3D positions (I've hacked [worse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45862606/8449629)), but unless you have strong reasons to do so, using one of the alternative plotting packages would probably be simpler.